# Refit c# + Firestore rules : How to set the "Request.Data" dictionary on Refit

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, refit

**Summary:**

I am using Refit to do Api Rest calls to my firestore database.

**Problem is** I have setup rules and it looks like the 'request.resource.data' dictionary of my request is not defined.

[image]

My condition in the firestore rule tab is:
*see UPDATE part below**

(I've also tried request.resource.data......)

**What I know:**
When I only check the auth.uid it works well but when I am adding this condition it fails.

**So Question is:**
How can I fill this attribute? :)
Thank you by advance :)

**UPDATE :**

Here are the concerned firestore rules:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of your rules showing how the function `containsLicence` is used? Note that the `resource` variable [1] binds to the documents being read/written. If you attempt to use `resource` in the context of query (`list`), the `resource` variable will not bound at rules evaluation time. Rules are not filter [2]

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource
[2] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I updated the question.

Comment: I decided to pass through a firebase cloud function (it works). But I am still interrested in the answer.

Comment: Based on the updated question, are you trying to use rules to authorize a write iff the user is signed in and is the owner of the user document and the updated data contains a `licence1` key? In that case you can use `resource.data.keys().hasOnly(...)` instead of having the `request.` prefix. The `request` and `resource` variables are two different variables that provide additional context for rules evaluation. Note that using `resource` will result in one read of the affected document. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#building_conditions for more details.

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as images.